# match ;ABC12;10;250.3 using regex java

Tags: java, regex

```
String regex = "^;[A-Z0-9]{5};[\\d]{1,};[\\d]{1,}.[\\d]{1,}";
String str = ";ABC12;10;250.3";
System.out.println(str.matches(regex));
```

The above regex works fine.

Consider the following strings

`str1=";ABC12;10;250.3"`

`str2=;ABB62;5;2.3`

`str3=;ABF02;8;25120.3`

`str4=;AKC12;11;2504.303`

Now i have the string as `String strToMatch= str1,str2,str3,str4`

How do i convert my regex expression above inorder to match the above string.

**Note :** There can be n number of comma separated values in the above string. And i also need to take care that the string `strToMatch` doesnot end with comma.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the regex with round brackets and repeat one or more times:

```
String regex = "^(;[A-Z0-9]{5};\\d+;\\d+\\.\\d+){1,}";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern instead: `(;[A-Z0-9]{5};[\\d]{1,};[\\d]{1,}\\.[\\d]{1,},?)+`

This has two differences to your pattern: first I use `\\.` to denote that this has to be a `.` because a single dot means "any character" in regex.

Then I used the grouping brackets `(...)` and the `+` at the end to say: "Look for this once or more". As the `,` is optional at the end, I added a `?`

If you want to get single matches to process using a Matcher later on, a simple modification should do the trick: `(;[A-Z0-9]{5};[\\d]{1,};[\\d]{1,}\\.[\\d]{1,}),?`

The `+` is gone and the `,?` is outside the grouping brackets, because those are now capturing brackets (as well).

Example:

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(;[A-Z0-9]{5};[\\d]{1,};[\\d]{1,}\\.[\\d]{1,}),?");
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(";ABC12;10;250.3,;ABB62;5;2.3,;ABF02;8;25120.3,;AKC12;11;2504.303");
while (matcher.find()) {
  System.out.println("Whole match: " + matcher.group());
  for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); ++i) {
    System.out.println("Group #" + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found below way of solving the problem.

```
String strToMatch = ";ABC12;10;250.3,;ABB62;5;2.3,;ABF02;8;25120.3,;AKC12;11;2504.303";
    if(strToMatch.endsWith(",") || strToMatch.startsWith(","))
        return false;
    else{
        String[] str = strToMatch.split(",");
        int count = 0;
        for (String s : str){
            String regex = ";[A-Z0-9]{5};\\d+;\\d+\\.\\d+";
            if(s.matches(regex))
                return false;
        }
        return true;

    }
```

Any simpler way than this?